# using toImage with a custom widget instead of RenderRepaintBoundary?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to save an image made inside of my application using:
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary/toImage.html

But the RenderRepaintBoundary used for capturing the image is always constrained by the screen. Is there a way of capturing a image of my widget layout that is larger than the screen bounds?

Comment: `RepaintBoundary` captures what has been rendered by it's child. If your child is bigger than the screen, it will capture more than the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RémiRousselet I was able to capture my image by wrapping my widget to UnconstrainedBox.